# How to handle ONE app being uploaded to app market with DIFFERENT screen sizes (Flex)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have built my react native to work for iPhone6. That is, the 'flex' values are geared for this phone. I want to upload this app to the app market, but there are so many different phones (iPhoneX, iPhone8 etc...). How do i release this app to the app market and cater for all these different screen sizes?

I know the different 'flex' values i need for each of the other phones, but how does the app market know which version with the right 'flex' is needed? I can't upload multiple versions of the app with different 'flex' values.

Answer (score 0):

The flex system is designed to divide your screen to different portions.

For example, if i have a container with 2 flex boxes, one of which has a flex of 2 and the other with a flex of 1, what will happen is that the container will be divided into 3 equal pieces(2 + 1) and the item with a flex of 2 will get two portions of those pieces. 
So when you design your app on an iphone 6, the percentage you assign to each of your components will be the same in a bigger device. The pixel count will be different but the aspect ratio for those components will stay the same.